# Implementation of simulated annealing; how to improve the performance?

Tags: optimization

## Update

I would find the global minima, the plotting shows that this function has many local minima.

```
f[x_] = 0.5 x^2 + Cos[Pi x] 2 Sin[Pi x] + Cos[Pi x] + 2 Sin[Pi x];
plt1 = Plot[f[x], {x, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0],Frame -> True]
```

According to the paper (http://ww.w.sliponline.org/Publications/Conferences/24/c24.pdf), I would implement the SA algorithm but the performance is very slow.

```
fTmp = fBest = xBest = xTmp = 999.0;
k = 0;
LIMIT = 10^6;
tTmp = tInit = 300;
Alpha = 0.999999999;

For [tTmp = tTmp * Alpha;, k < LIMIT, k++,
  xTmp = RandomReal[{-5, 5}];
  fTmp = f[xTmp];
  If [fTmp < fBest, fBest = fTmp; xBest = xTmp,
    PRA = N[Min[{1, Exp[-(fTmp - fBest)/tTmp]}]];
    R = RandomReal[{0.0, 1.0}];
    If [R < PRA, fBest = fTmp; xBest = xTmp; k++,];
  ];
tTmp = tTmp * Alpha;
];
Print[xBest]
Print[fBest]
```

---

```
-0.390741
-2.10428
```

Is it possible to improve the performance and accuracy of simulated annealing? Please feel free to comment, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To improve the accuracy, there are several things you can do:

1. Alter the parameters of the algorithm. Research papers utilizing SA on similar problems will describe their choice of parameters. Alternatively, you could run your own meta optimization on the parameters for your problem. For examples of different types, refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperparameter_optimization.
2. Perform multiple steps of optimization. In this case, you can re-run the algorithm, using the optimal solution in the first run in a new run, and so on. You could even use a different algorithm that searches about the optimal solution. In your specific case you're close to the optimal solution, so a brute force search about your solution may yield better results.

Performance can be improved by not using a fixed loop of 10^6 iterations. Instead, use the difference in the values between successive solutions as being less than some specified tolerance.

You can also utilize the multiple cores your system likely has to run several instances of the algorithm with different initial values. While this won't directly increase performance, you might get more out of the same resources during the same time period. If this is not sufficient I'd suggest trying some other global optimization algorithms, such as a Genetic Algorithm.

Comment: Would you suggest me a good example? Where can I find examples of website or blog about this topic?

Comment: I've added some additional information to the answer. I noticed that you're using a fixed loop instead of dynamic stopping criteria. As far as examples for research papers go, I don't have access to the papers that universities give their students. If you do, just google Simulated Annealing and see what scholarly articles come up and read through several that have examples. They may explain their choice of parameters or show how they optimized them.

Comment: No problem. If you feel the answer is sufficient, please mark it as an answer.